# How to add Blazor Webassembly to an existing ASP.NET Core web app with .NET 7?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

### Goal:

1. Existing ASP.NET Web app with .NET SDK 7 created with individual users as authentication option on new project wizard.
2. Add Blazor WebAssembly as SPA to be loaded on visiting a URL segment like {domain}/blazorApp
3. Components of Blazor WebAssembly are not intended to be embedded into ASP.NET views or pages.

### What have I tried till now

1. Create a new project representing the "existing" ASP.NET Web app with .NET 7
2. Add another project Blazor WebAssembly without the hosting or authentication options in new project wizard.
3. Add reference to the Blazor project in the existing app
4. Add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server` nuget package to the existing project
5. Add `<StaticWebAssetBaseBath>clientapp</StaticWebAssetBaseBath>` to Blazor csproj
6. In Blazor project > wwwroot > index.html add `<base href="/clientapp" />` and prefix all the paths of `link href` with "clientapp" as the URL segment for WASM
7. Add below to the existing project > Program.cs

```
app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/clientapp"), app1 =>
{
   app1.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles("/clientapp");
   app1.UseRouting();
   app1.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {
       //endpoints.MapControllers();
       endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/clientapp/{*path:nonfile}", "/clientapp/index.html");
   });
   //app1.UsePathBase("/clientapp");
   app1.UseStaticFiles();
   app1.UseStaticFiles("/clientapp");
});
```

7. Also add `app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();` to the existing project > Program.cs

[Source code on GitHub](https://github.com/ArvindRSingh/AddBlazorWasmToExistingAspNetCore)

### Issue

Getting HTTP 404 not found error on doing the above steps, running the project and navigating to /clientapp.

Answer (score 3):

Setting up the two projects is relatively simple.  You're almost there.  Sorting out the navigation can be a bit problematic!

Adding a WASM project is very simple.

1. Add a Web Assembly project to the solution - not Hosted.
2. Add the project as a dependency to the ASPNet Web project.
3. Add the following to the Web Project project file.

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="7.0.4" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

4. Add the following Middleware to the Web Project `Program`.

```cs
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles();
```

5. Copy `index.html` from the WASM project to the web project *Shared* folder and rename to `Wasm.cshtml`.
6. Add the following to the top of the page.

```cs
@page "/wasm"
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

7. Add a link in _Layout.cshtml.  This provides navigation from the ASPNet web site to the WASM SPA.

```cs
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Wasm">Blazor</a>
            </li>
```

7. Update Index in the WASM project.

```cs
@page "/Wasm"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
```

8. Update `NavMenu` in the WASM project.

```cs
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/">
                <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>Server
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/wasm">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </div>
```

You should now be able to navigate between the projects.

Comment: I've temporarily published my test project here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO75775295

Comment: There's also an article here on hosting multiple Blazor SPA's on a single site https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5287009/Blazor-Hydra-Hosting-Multiple-Blazor-SPAs-on-a-sin